# How to delete/unregister build agent on TFS 2015

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have set up TFS 2015 with dedicated server to store the build agent. However, when I delete the build agent on TFS 2015 app server, it still show up on build server, in windows "Services"

Now the build server display error because the service exist but not running.

How can a build agent be removed from TFS 2015?

Answer (score 18):

**Update:**

Just execute:

```
C:\YourAgentFolderPath\agent>agent\vsoagent /unconfigure
```

---

**Answer from year 2016:**

Go to the folder on the Build Server where you have unzipped your build agent.
*Some of the commenters mentioned, that they didn't have to delete the settings file, so you can try to skip this step, perhaps it is not necessary anymore*.

> Delete the settings.json file if it exists.

[image]

Open the commandline tool (cmd.exe) with admin rights!
Go to the folder as shown above in the screenshot.
Run the following command:

```
C:\YourAgentFolderPath\agent>agent\vsoagent /unconfigure
```

**Result (console log):**

> Removing EventLog source vsoagent.vsalm.YourAgentName. 
> Service
>   vsoagent.vsalm.YourAgentName is being removed from the system... 
> Service
>   vsoagent.vsalm.YourAgentName  was successfully removed from the system.
>   Attempt to stop service vsoagent.vsalm.YourAgentName.

Comment: surely you DON'T want to delete settings until after you run the command? I ended up with `The Agent is not properly configured, can't unconfigure this agent.`

Comment: that's what I thought too (about the upvotes) which confused me. I ended up having to reinstall the agent to be able to uninstall it again so I'd recommend trying first to unconfigure it before deleting the file (or renaming it)

Comment: I just had to do this and did not have to delete the settings.json file first.

Comment: It is very possible that things have changed meanwhile, because TFS has gotten some patches, updates in the meantime.... difficult to say now.